# HTML5 video tag with multiple bitrate videos?

Tags: ios, html, video, wifi

I have MP4 video files encoding at different bitrate to be compatible for both iOS on Wifi and Edge connection. I would like to have them progressive loaded form my website using HTML5 video tag.

**video_big.mp4 encoded for iOS on Wifi**
H.264 Baseline, 25fps, 640x480, 500kbps

**video_small.mp4 encoded for iOS on Edge/3G**
H.264 Baseline, 25fps, 320x240, 56kbps

My question is: How can I write the HTML5 video tag to serve **video_big.mp4** to iOS devices that connected through Wifi, and serve **video_small.mp4** to iOS devices that connected through Edge/3G? I'm running on PHP/Apache server. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't as currently there's no reliable method of detecting the type (or speed) of network a device is connected to.

At the moment the best you can do is to rely on media queries to assume (perhaps incorrectly) that a small screen means a small device and therefore give them the lower res video regardless of their network connection speed.

For example:

```
<video controls>
   <source src="video_small.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="all and (max-width:360px)">
   <source src="video_big.mp4 " type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: My main idea is to serve the right video file to the right connection speed, not to serve small video to small screen devices. Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: I know but as I said, unfortunately that isn't possible right now, so I was only showing you what could be done, potentially.

Comment: Well I'm note sure why this shouldn't be possible. It's possible to detect the buffer and therefore how fast a video is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [HTTP Live Streaming or HLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming). The configuration of that is based on M3U playlists and the videos are stored as MPEG-2 TS file into fragments of equal length, kept as .ts files.